# Do you need commas setting off a "when" clause in a sentence?

Tags: commas, when

As an example:

> In Quantum Physics when particles are observed their behaviour changes in relation to the fact they're being watched.

Does this sentence require a comma before *when* and a comma before *their*? In other words, should it be written as:

> In Quantum Physics, when particles are observed, their behaviour changes in relation to the fact they're being watched.

Comment: The commas are not offsetting the *when* clause. The second comma is offsetting the *when* clause. The first comma is offsetting the *in* clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many respects, this is a question of style rather than of right and wrong.

Personally, I would put a comma after *In Quantum Physics*: that clause is not critical to the meaning of the overall sentence; and I find it helps to pause there in order to understand the sentence quickly, i.e. on the first pass.

I have no strong opinion on the second comma: on the one hand, the *when* clause is critical to the sentence and therefore should not be offset; on the other hand, it does make it immediately clear that the verb *observed* belongs to *the particles* and not to *their behaviour*.

As an aside, why does *Quantum Physics* justify capital letters? It is not a proper noun, merely a branch of science like many hundreds of others.

Comment: I agree. Sometimes putting a comma makes the sentence seem more well structured, and sometimes it just interrupts the flow.